# Setup A CentOS server (on Desktop) That Replicates A Dedicated Server By A Hosting Company

Tags: centos, web-server

I am learning server administration, and for the right environment I am planning to install CentOS server on my desktop (using Virtualbox VM, Windows 7 Host).

Can someone direct me to a guide online that shows the exact (& secure) process, as to how these hosting companies (Hostgator, Rackspace etc) setup their servers?

I found [this tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-centos-5.2-p2), but it's not how Hostgator sets up its servers Hostgator Tech support person told me. He also won't disclose the process to me, for some reason. Can someone here help me out?

Comment: Well, I am looking for a tutorial to get started. Can someone confirm if [this tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/centos-5.1-server-lamp-email-dns-ftp-ispconfig) is good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than any software they use for internal management (e.g. monitoring, ssh keys, etc) the setup of a dedicated CentOS server from a hosting company shouldn't be that different from any other.

The tutorial you link to just runs through the basics, the options you choose here don't make dramatic differences, it just lets you select which packages to install. You can get the list of installed package groups from your hosted server with `yum grouplist`. If you find your missing a package on your local server, which is installed on the remote server, just install it.

Comment: Can you direct me to a good tut on installing a CentOS server? (The best one you know.)

Comment: @Aahan - no guide is the "best" as it can't answer questions for you. Instead, read the official documentation, understand your setup, and figure out how to answer your questions. http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Installation_Guide/